# Sequence of random variables with stopping rule

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales

A random variable $N$ whose support is natural numbers is such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \geq 1$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} X_i < 1.$$

$X_i$'s are independent and identically distributed as $U(0,1)$.

What is $\mathbb{E}[N]$?

I want an approach using the tools of renewal theory, stochastic processes.

My try:

Using the classical approach one can find that $\Pr \{N=n\} = \frac{n-1}{n!}$. And we thus get $\mathbb{E}[N] = e.$

**But how do we approach via stochastic processes?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can "approach via stochastic processes" even mean, if not what the classical approach does?

Comment: @Did By "approach via stochastic processes" I mean can we use the results of martingales, or renewal theory, or even Wald's lemma for example to get the result of this problem. I know that $N$ is a stopping time if we consider $X_i$'s to be the interarrival random variables, but I am not able to formulate it properly.

Comment: You do not use renewal theory in what you call "the classical approach"?

Comment: @Did Yeah. But can one use the results developed in renewal theory without explicitly finding the $\Pr\{N=n\}$ to get to the expected value of $N$?

Comment: This was already explained on the site but I re-posted an answer explaining the approach you have in mind (if I understand correctly what you are saying).

Comment: @Did Didn't know this was a repost. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the expectation of $N=\inf\{n\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n>1\}$ without computing its distribution, the most direct approach might be to enlarge the setting, considering, for every nonnegative $x$, the mean number $n(x)$ of random variables uniform on $(0,1)$ that are necessary to get a sum larger than $1$, *assuming that one starts at level $x$*.

Thus, $n(x)=E(N_x)$ where  $N_x=\inf\{n\mid x+X_1+\cdots+X_n>1\}$ and one is after $n(0)$.

First, $n(x)=0$ for every $x>1$. Second, for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, conditioning on the uniform random variable $X_1$, one gets the relation $$n(x)=1+E(n(x+X_1))$$ that is, $$n(x)=1+\int_0^{1-x}n(x+u)du=1+\int_x^1n(u)du$$ Differentiating, one gets $$n'(x)=-n(x)$$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, with $n(1)=1$, hence $$n(x)=e^{1-x}$$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, in particular,

> $$E(N)=n(0)=e$$

**Exercise:** Using the same approach, compute $E(N^{(2)})$, where $N^{(2)}=\inf\{n\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n>2\}$. You should find $E(N^{(2)})=e^2-e$. Give a simple argument to explain why $E(N^{(2)})<2E(N)$.

Comment: For the exercise mentioned: A simple argument would be that, from $0$ to $1+\epsilon$ we take $E(N)$ and then we are starting off with the level $\epsilon$ in the second independent set i.e., from $1$ to $2$. But using the similar approach won't we end up with $n^{(2)}(x)=e^{2-x}$ with $n^{(2)}(x)=0$ for $x>2$ and $E(N^{(2)}) = n^{(2)}(0)$?

Comment: Yes this is the argument showing that $E(N^{(2)})<2E(N)$. Regarding the reasoning that would lead to $n^{(2)}(x)=e^{2-x}$ (which does not hold if $x<1$), I suggest that you write it down carefully to understand at which step it goes astray.

Comment: $n(x)=1+E(n(x+X_1))$ doesn't work for this case, is it?

Comment: Huh? Why? (And sorry but this is not what I call writing the argument down carefully.)

Comment: I'm still not getting what's wrong with this: $n(x)=1+\int_0^{2-x}n(x+u)du=1+\int_x^2n(u)du$, for all $x\in [0,2]$. I'd appreciate more hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You see? The parameter $u$ refers to the possible values of $X_1$, always in $(0,1)$, but you integrate from $0$ to $2-x$, which is larger than $1$ for some values of $x$. Not true.

Comment: Got it! So the differential equation turns out to be $\frac{dy(x)}{dx }= e^{1-x}-y(x),$ with $y(1)=e$. Thanks for this awesome approach where one could solve for any **threshold** $c\in \mathbb{R}_+$.